# Java, Maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, compilation

I'm new to Maven and JSF and I have the following problem when compiling my project:

`Failed to execute goal on project ViewController: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.km.eFarmer:ViewController:war:1.0.1-alpha1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.sun.faces:jsf-api:jar:2.0.3-FCS, com.sun.faces:jsf-impl:jar:2.0.3-FCS, org.openfaces:openfaces:jar:3.0.2-KM, cssparser:cssparser:jar:0.9.5, it.eng.spago:sbi-utils:jar:3.3.0: Failure to find com.sun.faces:jsf-api:jar:2.0.3-FCS in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven.maven2 has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1`

Comment: My question is "How to solve this problem"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is means that the artifact `com.sun.faces:jsf-api:jar:2.0.3-FCS` is absent in repository  `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/`.

Indeed, there is no `jsf-api.jar` with version `2.0.3-FCS` in this repo.
There's a list of [available versions](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C3%7Cg%3a%22com.sun.faces%22%20AND%20a%3a%22jsf-api%22). So, you should change artifact version, or repository url

Comment: Those answer really helps me. Thanx. Problem is solved. But it steel very interesting for me, why maven is adding LastUpadted endings??

Comment: this etension is added to file when the artifact cannot be downloaded.  You can see more about metadata of artifacts here http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.2/maven-repository-metadata/repository-metadata.html

Answer (score -2):

Simple delete the folder local repository com/sun/faces and and retry it.

Comment: He can delete the data in his local repository all he wants, it's not going to help him if jsf-api version '2.0.3-FCS' does not actually exist on 'repo1.maven.org'.  What according to [this page](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C-130441585), it does not.

Comment: i doesnot helps. Maven creating dependencies with names like that: openfaces-3.0.2-KM.LastUpdated. And if i try to cut "lastUpadted" manually, maven while building says [INFO] Failed to parse Maven artifact C:\Users\Kirill\.m2\repository\org\openfaces\openfaces\3.0.2-KM\openfaces-3.0.2-KM.jar due to error in opening zip file

Comment: Than you should remove the folder org/openfaces and retry your build. Furthermore change your dependencies to http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.sun.faces|jsf-api|2.0.3|jar instead of 2.0.3-FCS...